# CentOS 7 SSHD and automounted home directories?

Tags: centos, nfs, sshd, automounting

- Create a home directory export on a separate server.
- Create a second, local home directory on the test CentOS 7 server.
- Make sure the local and NFS homedirs have the same UID, GID and permissions.
- Put the same .ssh/authorized_keys file, using a public key from the test account on a third server.
- SSHD via `systemctl` looks for `$OPTIONS`, but the variable is not set in `/etc/sysconfig/sshd`.

Case 1: Test SSH login using the local homedir. No password required.

Case 2: Test SSH login using the NFS/autofs homedir. authorized_keys gets ignored, but password works.

Case 3: `systemctl stop sshd` and `/usr/sbin/sshd` to start SSHD in the foreground. No password required with either homedir.

So, something is weird about the combination of the `systemctl` started SSHD and NFS/autofs homedirs?

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was an SELinux thing. Get onto the NFS server and execute

```
semanage fcontext -a -t ssh_home_t '/exports/[^/]+/\.ssh(/.*)?'
restorecon -v -r /exports/$USER
```

assuming you serve your NFS shares from `/exports'.