# CentOS 7: Nesting SELinux rules

Tags: centos, nfs, selinux

So, now that I've [figured out that `.ssh` files need the `ssh_home_t` file context](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/318095/centos-7-sshd-and-automounted-home-directories), now I need to figure out how to nest SELinux rules.

My first problem is that I can't find any list of SELinux file contexts that describe what they're intended use is. So, I may be off, here. I think I need to do three things, in this order:

1. Set every directory matching `/exports/home/$USER` to `nfs_t` *without* also matching any subdirectories under `$USER`. This tells my NFS server that home directories may legally be exported.
2. Set everything matching `/exports/home/$USER/.*` to... something? This is where a comprehensive list with descriptions would be handy. Does SELinux have a file context that generally designates files in a user's home directory?
3. Set everything matching `/exports/home/$USER/\.ssh(/.*)` *only* to `ssh_home_t`, so SSHD can permit the use of `authorized_keys`.

I need to invoke all three rules from the NFS server. And, I need to invoke the second and third rules *as an individual user* on that individual user's files from any host mounting the home directory. Because, obviously I hope, I will be squashing root on any host that mounts one of these home directories. A user is most likely to be creating files, including ssh files, from a host that isn't the NFS server.

---

**UPDATE**

I think I've figured out the right file contexts. Now, I just need to figure out the right regular expressions.

```
# semanage fcontext -a nfs_t '<regexp 1>'

# semanage fcontext -a user_home_t '<regexp 2>'

# semanage fcontext -a ssh_home_t '<regexp 3>'
```

where

- `<regexp 1>` catches `/exports/home/$USER` and doesn't go any further.
- `<regexp 2>` catches `/exports/home/$USER\.*` *except for* `exports/home/$USER/\.ssh(/.*)?`.
- `<regexp 3>` catches `exports/home/$USER/\.ssh(/.*)?`.

and `$USER` is string agnostic (ie. any user), and [POSIX Extended Regular Expressions](https://linux.die.net/man/1/egrep) appear to be disallowed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An easy, forehead-banging answer:

SELinux already has a default rule for `/export/home/*. Just drop the "s" and I was fixed.